# WinForm DataGrid Change cell color

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I have a DataGrid Object in a WinForm project

```
Friend WithEvents StatusTable As System.Windows.Forms.DataGrid
```

I also have a DataSet     `Private StatusDS As Data.DataSet`  with data that load in StatusTable like

```
StatusTable.DataSource = StatusDS.Tables("Channels")
```

Everything just works fine, But now I have to change the full row background color when column 3 and row x is "12"

my column 3 is a string and named Act

my column Act updates like

```
 Dim ts As New DataGridTableStyle

 Dim Act As New DataGridTextBoxColumn

 Act.MappingName = "Act"
 Act.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
 Act.HeaderText = "Action"
 
 ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(Act)

 StatusTable.TableStyles.Add(ts)
```

I can't find any way to change the row background color if the column act and row X is "12"

for example, if I have this table

```
Act
"1"
"12"
"1"
"4"
"12"
```

I have to change the color of rows number 2 and 5 (the first start in 1)

I have a lot of code and I try to put here the minimal.. tell me if you miss any information

Comment: Starting in .NET Core 3.1, `DataGrid` control are no longer available: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/winforms#removed-controls). If you want a long life for your project, switch to using `DataGridView` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note:**  The question is about Windows Forms .NET [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)
> which is deprecated and no longer available in .NET CORE and .NET 5.
> It's strongly recommended to upgrade your solution to use [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235);
>
> Anyways, if you are stuck with DataGrid and cannot easily update to DataGridView, the answer is for you.

**Customizing appearance of DataGrid**

To customize a [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) control, you usually need to define a [DataGridTableStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and add a few [DataGridColumnStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to it.

To have full control on appearance of the rows and columns, you usually need to create custom column styles by driving from one of the existing built-in column styles like [DataGridTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or [DataGridBoolColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridboolcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) or the base [DataGridColumnStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridcolumnstyle?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). Then you can customize the behavior by overriding properties and methods of the class.

You will find this article very useful:

- [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996485(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

**Example - Change row background color based on cell value of a specific column**

Here I create a new column style by deriving from the built-in [DataGridTextBoxColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and overriding its [Paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn.paint?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method. In the method, I check if the value of the first column is odd number:

```
public class MyDataGridTextBoxColumn : DataGridTextBoxColumn
{
    protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source,
        int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
    {
        var idCellValue = ((DataRowView)source.List[rowNum])["Id"];
        var brush = backBrush;
        if (idCellValue != DBNull.Value && ((int)idCellValue) % 2 == 1)
            brush = Brushes.Yellow;
        base.Paint(g, bounds, source, rowNum, brush, foreBrush, alignToRight);
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add(1, "A");
    dt.Rows.Add(2, "B");
    dt.Rows.Add(3, "C");

    var dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    var ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn()
    { MappingName = "Id", HeaderText = "Id" });
    ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(new MyDataGridTextBoxColumn()
    { MappingName = "Name", HeaderText = "Name" });
    dg.TableStyles.Add(ts);

    this.Controls.Add(dg);
    dg.DataSource = dt;
}
```

And you will see the result:

[image]

**Note:** It definitely makes more sense to not put any business logic inside the custom Column, instead you can raise a Formatting event, and put any logic inside the event handler and pass formatting data back to the column, using event arguments.